# How to add a point to an AutoCAD drawing using the command line

Tags: vba, command-line-interface, autocad

I work in the field of GIS and I am working with contours, point heights and other datasets which have elevation related information.

In a GIS software (for example QGIS), I can extract the geometry attributes of a line, polygon or a set of points. Consequently, I can also write the set of points and their geometrical attributes to a text file through Python scripting.

There a person who does not use QGIS and is specifically unaware of GIS based techniques. Consequently, the files that I generate using QGIS are completely useless to him. Further, he also works on a Mac OS based computer and therefore the GIS based Autocad is also not available with him.

Therefore, the question how can I provide a set of points with their coordinates, or a polygon with points to AutoCAD via a command line. For example, do we have a command or set of commands like

```
SET ORIGIN TO 50000,5000 
ADD POINT 51000, 51000 

...
```

Answer (score 0):

In AutoCAD he may use command `SCRIPT`.
You crerate `.scr` text file.

Example file with coordinates You can find [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-import-a-list-of-coordinates-into-AutoCAD.html)